# http-server Node Package Does Not Read .env file

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, httpserver, .env

In higher environments - I have my DockerFile running the files under the dist folder with the command `http-server dist -p 3000`  and the .env file is not picked

On my local I use `node` to run my server and the `.env` file is picked up. Its a clear indication that http-server doesn't care about the .env file. The [documentation for http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) doesn't say much about the .env file. So, before making any changes in higher env I want to be doubly sure about the same. Anyone knows about any alternative or should I go ahead making changes in higher env DockerFile?

Comment: why would `http-server`, or anything else for that matter, care about your `.env` file? That's not their responsibility: you load `.env` files with [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) so that they're folded in Node's `process.env`, and everything taps into _that_ for their env var needs, as that's the only place code is supposed to look for environment variables.